# Azure website need to connect on-premises SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-vpn

we are migrating existing website to Microsoft Azure Websites (PaaS). The application access the on-premises MS-SQL Database for some data. we are unable to provide access through firewall (for IP, because there is no static IP for website).

Is there any other solution for it. is VPN is the solution then it possible to create VPN for "Website" to "On-Premises" MS-SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an Azure Virtual Network to allow you to securely access your on-prem database from Azure. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-network/

You can then connect your Azure Website to that Virtual Network to let your website connect to your database.
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/

Comment: Thank you Zain Rizvi, i'll let you know if any clarification required on this

Answer (score 3):

easiest way would be to use Hybrid Connect to connect your Azure Website to an on-premises SQL Server without messing around with networks...

have a look at [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started/) for step by step instructions on how to configure Hybrid Connect

Comment: To be complete, I think your answer should include the fact that a hybrid connection utilizes BizTalk Services, which is a heavier-weight solution than using a virtual network. Also, I'm not sure why you think you need to "mess around" with virtual networks. They're straightforward to set up, and they provide a secure network for resources to connect.

Comment: from a simplicity perspective, it's easier to simply install the agent and exposed the on-premise resource than defining VNET/configuring subnet and exposing more resources on the VNET than what's required

Comment: i know this is an old post, but this a viable option if the target is non-windows machine?